# SalesForce Dashboard Links in IE

Tags: dashboard

I am new to SalesForce, and none of the links in my dashboards are working in IE explorer (IE9), but they work just fine in Chrome. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Welcome to SFSE. Which links to the dashboards are you referring to; on your Home tab or when selecting a dashboard from the Dashboard tab? Or something else?